# Mac Mini has loud fan, won't power up

Tags: startup, mac-mini

My intel-based mac mini (Model A1283, EMC 2336) refuses to boot. When I plug it in, the fan spins up very loudly, but then nothing happens when I hit the power button. I don't get a boot chime, and the power light on the front doesn't turn on.

I've followed the directions [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) for resetting the SMC, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

What are my options? Do I need to schlep it in for some applecare attention?

Comment: My Mac Mini is having exactly the same issue, although it is booting up occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be to systematically go through the manufacturer steps for [troubleshooting a mac mini that won't boot](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2622). Even if you don't see the power light - do run through the [no video steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2714) as well - it might save you a trip or a call with a tech.

Best of luck!

Comment: Sadly, I stepped through all of those as well. Looks like it's time to belly up to the genius bar.

Comment: Indeed - the parts in them are fairly low cost as far as repairs go - hopefully it's ram or something else cheap :-) I'm hoping my mini lasts until a SSD + 1 TB Thunder Mini arrives on the scenes. (one can dream, no?)

Comment: If it's a ram issue, you would hear some beeps when you try to turn it on! Have you tried resetting your PRAM?

Comment: I don't believe the intel mac's use PRAM, do they?

Comment: NVRAM is the correct term, however the command keys **option + command + P + R** used to reset NVRAM will likely keep PRAM on everyone's mind for quite a long time.